# Error : Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException

Tags: java, android

I'm getting this error while running my project.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

can anyone suggest me how to correct it?

This is my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'




android {




 compileSdkVersion 22

  buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shreyatakkar.student"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

}
```

Comment: Post something userful

Comment: this is duplicate question please find on stakeoverflow

Answer (score 1):

I too was having this error after updating to the latest Android Studio.I fixed it by adding `multiDexEnabled true` in `build.gradle` within `defaultConfig`.

Example:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.shreyatakkar.student"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: It's possible but i don't think so.

Comment: i did and now this error message is being displayed :     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/util/LogWriter.class

Comment: i added this and it worked !          

                                      
configurations     
{

    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'

}

Comment: Can you please add it as a separate answer with some details so that it will help others with the same problem..